# Update an attribute for all users in profile Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I've a model:

```
class GenerateCertificate(models.Model):

    username = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cert_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=15,
        default='',
        blank=True,
        editable=False)
    cert_password = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        default='',
        blank=True,
        editable=False)
    key_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=15,
        default='',
        blank=True,
        editable=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.username)
```

I want to update the attributes `cert_name`, `cert_password` and `key_name` and set value `''` in all of these attributes. It is easy to do it for one user through the following:

```
def DeleteUserData(self, request, queryset):
    for qs in queryset:
        username = str(qs.username)
        #get user data from database
        user = GenerateCertificate.objects.get(username__username=username)
        keyname = user.key_name
        certname = user.cert_name

        GenerateCertificate.objects.filter(username__username=username).update(
            cert_name='')
        GenerateCertificate.objects.filter(username__username=username).update(
            cert_password='')
        GenerateCertificate.objects.filter(username__username=username).update(
            key_name='')
```

but how to do it for all the users in the database, all at once?

I am using Django 2.0.6 and Python 3.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can update all objects of `GenerateCertificate` model at once

```
data_dict = {'cert_name': '', 'cert_password': '', 'key_name': ''}
GenerateCertificate.objects.all().update(**data_dict)
```

Comment: why is the filter irrelevant?

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge He wants to update `GenerateCertificate` object for all users, and each User has only one `GenerateCertificate` object.